# How to split text to header and content with regexp?

Tags: java, regex

Oracle backup log file contains header and content like this:

```
Starting backup at 14-JUL-13
channel d1: starting compressed incremental level 0 datafile backup set
channel d1: specifying datafile(s) in backup set
input datafile file number=00004 name=/oradata/reports1/qqq01.dbf
input datafile file number=00001 name=/oradata/reports1/aaa01.dbf
input datafile file number=00002 name=/oradata/reports1/xxx01.dbf
input datafile file number=00003 name=/oradata/reports1/bbbs01.dbf
<...>

Starting backup at 15-JUL-13
current log archived
channel d1: starting compressed archived log backup set
channel d1: specifying archived log(s) in backup set
input archived log thread=1 sequence=580 RECID=288 STAMP=820739223
input archived log thread=1 sequence=581 RECID=289 STAMP=820739223
<...>

Starting backup at 16-JUL-13
<...>
```

I tried to split it to header and content using RegExp and Java.

My bad working regexp (non Java format):

```
 ^Starting backup at \d{2}-[A-Z]{3}-\d{2}$+((?:.|\\n)+?)
```

Java flags DOTALL and MULTILINE enabled.

It returns header but content is empty.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which version of Java are you using?

Comment: <...> it means "more lines"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use DOTALL flag.

```
String s = "Starting backup at 14-JUL-13\n" + 
        "channel d1: starting compressed incremental level 0 datafile backup set\n" + 
        "channel d1: specifying datafile(s) in backup set\n" + 
        "input datafile file number=00004 name=/oradata/reports1/qqq01.dbf\n" + 
        "input datafile file number=00001 name=/oradata/reports1/aaa01.dbf\n" + 
        "input datafile file number=00002 name=/oradata/reports1/xxx01.dbf\n" + 
        "input datafile file number=00003 name=/oradata/reports1/bbbs01.dbf\n" + 
        "<...>\n" + 
        "\n" + 
        "Starting backup at 15-JUL-13\n" + 
        "current log archived\n" + 
        "channel d1: starting compressed archived log backup set\n" + 
        "channel d1: specifying archived log(s) in backup set\n" + 
        "input archived log thread=1 sequence=580 RECID=288 STAMP=820739223\n" + 
        "input archived log thread=1 sequence=581 RECID=289 STAMP=820739223\n" + 
        "<...>\n" + 
        "\n" + 
        "Starting backup at 16-JUL-13\n" + 
        "<...>";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?s)(Starting backup at \\d{1,2}-[A-Z]{3,4}-\\d{1,2})\\n(.*?)(?=\\n\\n|$)").matcher(s);
while(m.find())
{
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
}
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vN3sH3/65)

Group index 1 contains the header part and  group index 2 contains the content part.

Answer (score 1):

```
(Starting backup at \d{1,2}-[A-Z]{3,4}-\d{1,2})([\s\S]*?)(?=\n{2}|$)
```

You can try this.See demo.No need of `s` flag.

https://regex101.com/r/vN3sH3/66

or

```
(Starting backup at \d{1,2}-[A-Z]{3,4}-\d{1,2})([\s\S]*?)(?=Starting backup at \d{1,2}-[A-Z]{3,4}-\d{1,2}|$)
```

https://regex101.com/r/vN3sH3/67